# Can't put index value inside brackets using RegEx

Tags: javascript, regex

There are two strings. I'm trying to put index value inside empty brackets:

```
var capacity = 'room[price_group_ids][][capacity]';
var group = 'room[price_group_ids][][group][%s][]';
```

For example, If an index is 1, they should be:

```
var capacity = 'room[price_group_ids][1][capacity]';
var group = 'room[price_group_ids][1][group][%s][]';
```

And if the index is 2, they should look like as the following:

```
var capacity = 'room[price_group_ids][2][capacity]';
var group = 'room[price_group_ids][2][group][%s][]';
```

What I've tried and it gives unexpected result:

```
var index = 2;

var capacity = 'room[price_group_ids][][capacity]'.replace(/\[(.+?)\]/g, "[" + index +"]"); // Should become room[price_group_ids][2][capacity]
var group = 'room[price_group_ids][][group][%s][]'.replace(/\[(.+?)\]/g, "[" + index +"]"); // Should become room[price_group_ids][2][group][%s][]
```

I'm not good at RegEx and looking for an advice on how to resolve that

Comment: fyi, a good resource for testing regular expressions is https://regex101.com/

Answer (score 1):

A simple `replace` should work here.

This will only replace the first occurrence of `[]`, so you don't have to worry about others. `g` flag is used to replace globally i-e all the occurrences of the specified value

```
capacity.replace('[]', `[${index}]`);
```

```js
var index = 2;
var capacity = 'room[price_group_ids][][capacity]';
var group = 'room[price_group_ids][][group][%s][]';

capacity = capacity.replace('[]', `[${index}]`);
group = group.replace('[]', `[${index}]`);

console.log(capacity)
console.log(group)
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you want to match first occurrence of `[]` so don't use `g` flag. Also no need to match anything else `(.+?)` , just `/\[\]/` is enough.

Another way is to simply replace string `[]` with `[1]`

```js
let index = 2
console.log('room[price_group_ids][][capacity]'.replace(/\[\]/, `[${index}]`));
console.log('room[price_group_ids][][group][%s][]'.replace(/\[\]/, `[${index}]`));
```

Answer (score 1):

The reg exp `/\[(.+?)\]/g` matches 1-or-more of anything between `[]` brackets.  You want to detect `[` and `]` right next to each other; simply:

```
/\[\]/
```

Also, you want to ditch the `g` at the end, unless you want the replacement to occur for *all* occurrences of `[]` -- the `g` means `global`.

But there are non-regex approaches, too, as shown in the other answers.